# How do I right align a button next to a label in a form?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried adding `.pull-right` to the button but both elements are not vertically aligned anymore and the margin to the next `.form-group` of `input` elements becomes smaller.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nmvk6/

`HTML`

```
<form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Type</label>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control half-width-form-control">
            <option value="foo">foo</option>
            <option value="bar">bar</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control half-width-form-control" type="number"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the form horizontal version with `.form-horizontal`, and add `.control-label` to get your labels vertically aligned :

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Type</label>
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control half-width-form-control">
                <option value="foo">foo</option>
                <option value="bar">bar</option>
            </select>
            <input class="form-control half-width-form-control" type="number"></input>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/Nmvk6/6/)**

[image]

[>> Bootstrap doc, about horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Comment: This aligns the top of the label and the button vertically. How do I retain the middle vertical alignment?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. See the picture, they are middle vertical aligned, no ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I broke it with other CSS.